# Why in some case parallel computation is slower using pp module of python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

Look at the codes. When the parameters of genMotifs is set n_seq=5000 and n_pos=10, the parallel version getPairedSeqNames3 and getPairedSeqNames1 is much more slower. But when n_seq=50 and n_pos=2000, the parallel version perform better. Unfortunately the data I'm dealing with is more like n_seq=5000 and n_pos=10. Could anyone tell me the reason why this would happen? Is there any way to make the parallel version perform better when n_seq=5000 and n_pos=10?

Here are the codes:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import pp, sys, random, time
def getMotif_SeqName(Motifs):
    return dict([(uid, set(Motifs[uid].keys())) for uid in Motifs.keys()])

def getPairedList(uids):
    return [(id1, id2) for i, id1 in enumerate(uids) for id2 in uids[i:] if id1 != id2]

def is_overlap(pos_pair):
    (posA, posB) = pos_pair
    if max(posA) < min(posB) or min(posA) > max(posB):
        return False
    else:
        return True

def caclDist(pos_pair):
    (posA, posB) = pos_pair
    d1 = min(posB) - max(posA)
    d2 = min(posA) - max(posB)
    return {True: d1, False: -d2}[d1 > d2]

def getDist(posA, posB, low, high):
    comb = [(i, j) for i in posA for j in posB]
    not_overlap = [e for e in comb if not is_overlap(e)]
    distances = map(caclDist, not_overlap)
    CoDist = {}
    for i, d in enumerate(distances):
        if abs(d) >= low and abs(d) <= high:
            CoDist[not_overlap[i]] = d
    return CoDist

def getDist2(uidA, uidB, seqname, posA, posB, low, high):
    comb = [(i, j) for i in posA for j in posB]
    not_overlap = [e for e in comb if not is_overlap(e)]
    distances = map(caclDist, not_overlap)
    CoDist = {}
    for i, d in enumerate(distances):
        if abs(d) >= low and abs(d) <= high:
            CoDist[not_overlap[i]] = d
    return (uidA, uidB, seqname, CoDist)

def ppCacl(job_server, inputs, equation, funs, packages, Progress=True):
    num_inputs = len(inputs) / 100 + 1
    jobs = [job_server.submit(equation, pars, funs, packages) for pars in inputs]
    return [job() for job in jobs]


def ssCacl(inputs, equation):
    ps = []
    for i, (X, n, m, N) in enumerate(inputs):
        ps.append(equation(X, n, m, N))
    return ps

def getPairedSeqNames1(Motifs):
    SeqNames = getMotif_SeqName(Motifs)
    MotifPairs = set(getPairedList(Motifs.keys()))
    num_MotifPairs = len(MotifPairs)
    print "%s pairs to go" % num_MotifPairs
    num_MotifPairs = num_MotifPairs / 100 + 1
    PairedMotifs = {}

    for i, (uidA, uidB) in enumerate(MotifPairs):
        intersect = list(SeqNames[uidA] & SeqNames[uidB])
        if intersect:
            PosA = Motifs[uidA]
            PosB = Motifs[uidB]

            sys.stderr.write("Progress:%d%%\t%s\t%s\r" % (i / num_MotifPairs, uidA, uidB))
            positions = [(PosA[seqname], PosB[seqname], 10, 250) for seqname in intersect]
            distances = ppCacl(job_server, positions, getDist, (is_overlap, caclDist), (), False)
            distances = dict([(intersect[i], d) for i, d in enumerate(distances) if d])
            if distances:
                PairedMotifs[(uidA, uidB)] = distances
    return PairedMotifs

def getPairedSeqNames2(Motifs):
    SeqNames = getMotif_SeqName(Motifs)
    MotifPairs = set(getPairedList(Motifs.keys()))
    num_MotifPairs = len(MotifPairs)
    print "%s pairs to go" % num_MotifPairs
    num_MotifPairs = num_MotifPairs / 100 + 1
    PairedMotifs = {}

    for i, (uidA, uidB) in enumerate(MotifPairs):
        intersect = list(SeqNames[uidA] & SeqNames[uidB])
        if intersect:
            PosA = Motifs[uidA]
            PosB = Motifs[uidB]

            sys.stderr.write("Progress:%d%%\t%s\t%s\r" % (i / num_MotifPairs, uidA, uidB))
            positions = [(PosA[seqname], PosB[seqname], 10, 250) for seqname in intersect]
            distances = ssCacl(positions, getDist)
            distances = dict([(intersect[i], d) for i, d in enumerate(distances) if d])
            if distances:
                PairedMotifs[(uidA, uidB)] = distances
    return PairedMotifs

def getPairedSeqNames3(Motifs):
    SeqNames = getMotif_SeqName(Motifs)
    MotifPairs = set(getPairedList(Motifs.keys()))
    num_MotifPairs = len(MotifPairs)
    print "%s pairs to go" % num_MotifPairs
    num_MotifPairs = num_MotifPairs / 100 + 1
    PairedMotifs = {}
    positions = []

    for i, (uidA, uidB) in enumerate(MotifPairs):
        intersect = list(SeqNames[uidA] & SeqNames[uidB])
        if intersect:
            PosA = Motifs[uidA]
            PosB = Motifs[uidB]

            sys.stderr.write("Progress:%d%%\t%s\t%s\r" % (i / num_MotifPairs, uidA, uidB))
            positions.extend([(uidA, uidB, seqname, PosA[seqname], PosB[seqname], 10, 250) for seqname in intersect])

    distances = ppCacl(job_server, positions, getDist2, (is_overlap, caclDist), (), False)
    for (uidA, uidB, seqname, CoDist) in distances:
        if CoDist:
            if not PairedMotifs.has_key((uidA, uidB)):
                PairedMotifs[(uidA, uidB)] = {}
            PairedMotifs[(uidA, uidB)][seqname] = CoDist
    return PairedMotifs


def genMotifs(n_seq=5000, n_pos=10):
    digits = range(1, 60000)
    Motifs = {}
    uids = random.sample(digits, 50)
    for uid in uids:
        seqnames = random.sample(digits, random.randint(0, n_seq))
        Motifs[uid] = {}
        for seqname in seqnames:
            Motifs[uid][seqname] = genPos(random.randint(0, n_pos))
    return Motifs


def genPos(n):
    return [(random.randint(0, 3000),random.randint(0, 3000)) for i in xrange(0,n)]


job_server = pp.Server()

Motifs = genMotifs()
timestamp = time.time()
getPairedSeqNames1(Motifs)
print time.time() - timestamp
timestamp = time.time()
getPairedSeqNames2(Motifs)
print time.time() - timestamp
timestamp = time.time()
getPairedSeqNames3(Motifs)
print time.time() - timestamp


Motifs = genMotifs(50, 2000)
timestamp = time.time()
getPairedSeqNames1(Motifs)
print time.time() - timestamp
timestamp = time.time()
getPairedSeqNames2(Motifs)
print time.time() - timestamp
timestamp = time.time()
getPairedSeqNames3(Motifs)
print time.time() - timestamp
```

the result on my computer:

```
1225 pairs to go
57.377081871    16666   20431
1225 pairs to go
15.1005380154   16666   20431
1225 pairs to go
59.9019329548   16666   20431
1225 pairs to go
43.1178700924   11721   46015
1225 pairs to go
77.7199709415   11721   46015
1225 pairs to go
10.1687381268   11721   46015
```

The cProfile of getPairedSeqNames3 n_seq=5000 n_pos=10
[image]

The cProfile of getPairedSeqNames3 n_seq=10 n_pos=5000
[image]

The cProfile of getPairedSeqNames3 n_seq=20 n_pos=2500
[image]

Comment: Is `pp` the library at http://www.parallelpython.com/ ? (Might be handy to state which version as well - 1.6.2 seems to be the latest on PyPi)

Comment: Could you provide a simpler example that shows this behaviour? Anyway it happened to me also using the `multiprocessing` module. In that case it was because I was locking some objects that didn't need a lock and also the processes communicated too often(they were processing sequence of integers, one at a time, while passing ranges of integers is much more efficient).

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but your code could be a lot better if you used `zip` (instead of `distances = dict([(intersect[i], d) for i, d in enumerate(distances) if d])` write `distances = dict((i, d) for i, d in zip(intersect, distances) if d)` because most of the time, you don't need the index. And use generators.

Comment: @jon-clements That's it. I'm using the latest 1.6.2

Comment: @Bakuriu I'm afriad the complexity is one of the reason. Simpler example might not shows this behaviour. I'll give it a try. The Motif object makes the different.

Comment: @hughdbrown Thanks for your improvement.

Comment: I read the cProfile output to be saying that the higher the `n_seq` goes, the more time is spent waiting for a lock. When `n_seq` is 10, it doesn't look as if it even uses the threading API. But I am not an expert on this package at all.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code to use better python idioms:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import pp
import sys
import random
import time
from collections import defaultdict

job_server = pp.Server()


def getMotif_SeqName(Motifs):
    return {uid: set(d.keys()) for uid, d in Motifs.items()}


def getPairedList(uids):
    return [(id1, id2) for i, id1 in enumerate(uids) for id2 in uids[i:] if id1 != id2]


def is_overlap(pos_pair):
    (posA, posB) = pos_pair
    return not (max(posA) < min(posB) or min(posA) > max(posB))


def caclDist(pos_pair):
    (posA, posB) = pos_pair
    d1 = min(posB) - max(posA)
    d2 = min(posA) - max(posB)
    return d1 if d1 > d2 else -d2


def getDist(posA, posB, low, high):
    comb = ((i, j) for i in posA for j in posB)
    not_overlap = [e for e in comb if not is_overlap(e)]
    distances = map(caclDist, not_overlap)
    return {
        not_over: d
        for not_over, d in zip(not_overlap, distances)
        if low <= abs(d) <= high
    }


def getDist2(uidA, uidB, seqname, posA, posB, low, high):
    return (uidA, uidB, seqname, getDist(posA, posB, low, high))


def ppCacl(job_server, inputs, equation, funs, packages, Progress=True):
    jobs = (job_server.submit(equation, pars, funs, packages) for pars in inputs)
    return [job() for job in jobs]


def ssCacl(inputs, equation):
    return [equation(X, n, m, N) for (X, n, m, N) in inputs]


def getPairedSeqNames1(Motifs, SeqNames, MotifPairs):
    num_MotifPairs = len(MotifPairs)
    print "%s pairs to go" % num_MotifPairs
    num_MotifPairs = num_MotifPairs / 100 + 1
    PairedMotifs = {}

    for i, (uidA, uidB) in enumerate(MotifPairs):
        intersect = list(SeqNames[uidA] & SeqNames[uidB])
        if intersect:
            PosA = Motifs[uidA]
            PosB = Motifs[uidB]

            sys.stderr.write("Progress:%d%%\t%s\t%s\r" % (i / num_MotifPairs, uidA, uidB))
            positions = [(PosA[seqname], PosB[seqname], 10, 250) for seqname in intersect]
            distances = ppCacl(job_server, positions, getDist, (is_overlap, caclDist), (), False)
            distances = {index: d for index, d in zip(intersect, distances) if d}
            if distances:
                PairedMotifs[(uidA, uidB)] = distances
    return PairedMotifs


def getPairedSeqNames2(Motifs, SeqNames, MotifPairs):
    num_MotifPairs = len(MotifPairs)
    print "%s pairs to go" % num_MotifPairs
    num_MotifPairs = num_MotifPairs / 100 + 1
    PairedMotifs = {}

    for i, (uidA, uidB) in enumerate(MotifPairs):
        intersect = list(SeqNames[uidA] & SeqNames[uidB])
        if intersect:
            PosA = Motifs[uidA]
            PosB = Motifs[uidB]

            sys.stderr.write("Progress:%d%%\t%s\t%s\r" % (i / num_MotifPairs, uidA, uidB))
            positions = ((PosA[seqname], PosB[seqname], 10, 250) for seqname in intersect)
            distances = ssCacl(positions, getDist)
            distances = {index: d for index, d in zip(intersect, distances) if d}
            if distances:
                PairedMotifs[(uidA, uidB)] = distances
    return PairedMotifs


def getPairedSeqNames3(Motifs, SeqNames, MotifPairs):
    num_MotifPairs = len(MotifPairs)
    print "%s pairs to go" % num_MotifPairs
    num_MotifPairs = num_MotifPairs / 100 + 1
    PairedMotifs = defaultdict(dict)
    positions = []

    for i, (uidA, uidB) in enumerate(MotifPairs):
        intersect = list(SeqNames[uidA] & SeqNames[uidB])
        if intersect:
            PosA = Motifs[uidA]
            PosB = Motifs[uidB]

            sys.stderr.write("Progress:%d%%\t%s\t%s\r" % (i / num_MotifPairs, uidA, uidB))
            positions.extend([(uidA, uidB, seqname, PosA[seqname], PosB[seqname], 10, 250) for seqname in intersect])

    distances = ppCacl(job_server, positions, getDist2, (is_overlap, caclDist), (), False)
    for (uidA, uidB, seqname, CoDist) in distances:
        if CoDist:
            PairedMotifs[(uidA, uidB)][seqname] = CoDist
    return PairedMotifs


def genMotifs(n_seq, n_pos):
    digits = range(1, 60000)
    uids = random.sample(digits, 50)
    return {
        uid: {
            seqname: genPos(random.randint(0, n_pos))
            for seqname in random.sample(digits, random.randint(0, n_seq))
        }
        for uid in uids
    }


def genPos(n):
    return [(random.randint(0, 3000), random.randint(0, 3000)) for _ in xrange(n)]


def driver(Motifs):
    SeqNames = getMotif_SeqName(Motifs)
    MotifPairs = set(getPairedList(Motifs.keys()))
    for fn in (getPairedSeqNames1, getPairedSeqNames2, getPairedSeqNames3):
        timestamp = time.time()
        fn(Motifs, SeqNames, MotifPairs)
        print time.time() - timestamp


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for x, y in ((5000, 10), (50, 2000)):
        print '=' * 30
        driver(genMotifs(x, y))
```

I can't promise you that this will be faster. If you are looking to optimize your code, I'd look at profiling with cProfile or using numpy or cython.

Comment: My codes are a mess. Thanks you for cleaning up the codes. What I'm trying to do is figuring out why the parallel version does not work better.

Comment: The parallel version behave differently when the Motif object is different. It will get slower as the n_seq increased.